# Any latest edition or successor of "Invertebrate zoology" by Ruppert & Barnes 2003?

Tags: zoology, book-recommendation, invertebrates

I have the 6th edition of the textbook "Invertebrate Zoology" by Ruppert and Barnes from 1993. I know there is a 7th edition from 2003, but is there and will there ever be a 8th edition? Assuming they should come every 10 years, shouldn't there have been one in 2013? So if Ruppert & Barnes retired, is there any more recent successor **or alternative**?

Comment: There is no 8th edition. Barnes died a long time ago, in 1993. The latest edition was written by Edward Ruppert and Richard Fox, and it is the 2003 one. If you want to know if there are plans for a new edition you can email one of the authors or the publisher.

Comment: BTW Barnes is listed as 1 of the authors for the 2003 edition as well.

Comment: He will be listed on any future edition. It's just like Lehninger's "Principles of biochemistry", or Guyton's "Medical physiology": they are all dead, but they are kept as the main author.

Comment: Thanks! I would still like to know whether there is a more recent alternative.

Comment: Found it! I created my own answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A worthy successor to this book series is "Invertebrates" by Richard C. Brusca et al. The latest edition being from 2016, so exactly what I was looking for.

[https://www.amazon.com/gp/product/1605353752/ref=pe_353720_261047730_em_sp_C_1p_1_ti](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1605353752)

Comment: I studied invertebrate zoology using Barne's book, and I was reluctant to buy a book different from the classic one. I checked comments on the Brusca's book, and I was surprised that all of them are good ones (5 stars). It seems it's a better alternative to Barnes' book (7th edition 2003), as the last edition (3rd) was published in 2016 and includes the recent taxonomical reviews (e.g. new phyla, merged ones, etc.). I'm considering buying this; the price is quite reasonable compared to the other one.